# Docker cannot access any Internet URL during build

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing http://www.google.com
```

On my Windows 10 machine, I run `docker build .` and get the following:

[image]

Basically, Docker is unable to access any Internet URL I try.  I can run the same Dockerfile on my Windows Server 2019 Core machine and everything works fine.  I'm running Docker version 18.09.2 and haven't updated it recently.  This was working a few days ago, so it's a new issue.  I've tried restarting the Docker engine and also rebooting.  I've also tried a `docker system prune`.  Any ideas what broke this?  I'd rather not reinstall Docker if possible.

Docker Info:

```
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           18.09.2
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.10.8
 Git commit:        6247962
 Built:             Sun Feb 10 04:12:31 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.2
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.24)
  Go version:       go1.10.6
  Git commit:       6247962
  Built:            Sun Feb 10 04:28:48 2019
  OS/Arch:          windows/amd64
  Experimental:     false
```

**Update:** Seems to be DNS related.  I can ping things.

[image]

Comment: This is a bug in latest servercore images `https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1029`

Comment: Try to put this in front of your test `Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')`

Comment: @GregorySuvalian Cool!  That fixed the problem.  So perhaps my Windows Server machine has an older version of that image.  Could also be an isolation level difference (My Windows 10 machine is using hyerpv and Windows Server is running in process)

Comment: Not sure but it's a known issue per Microsoft folks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue with ltsc2019 images (https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/1029). Put following at the start of your dockerfile or before entrypoint
`Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex (Get-NetAdapter).IfIndex -ServerAddresses ('8.8.8.8')`

Comment: Only drawback is this setting isn't permanent.  It would need to be run every time before every single RUN command that used DNS.

Comment: No, it's one time at the start of the file or in your entrypoint

Comment: Hmm yes okay you're correct.  Not sure why it wasn't working before, maybe something stuck in the build cache or something..

Comment: Also to me it seems like this is more likely a Windows 10 1903 bug, not a windowsservercore image bug.  It repros on Windows 10 using servercore:ltsc2019 as well as servercore:1903 (in process or isolation) and it does NOT repro on Windows Server 2019 using any image.  I also think that's around the time it stopped working, when the May updates were installed.